# Django ModelMultipleChoiceField : Iterating through the data

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to display the data from a ModelMultipleChoiceField, and have tried to iterate for the objects, but I am getting funky results. Thanks for the help!

```
{{ chef.meal }}
```

Renders

```
[<Meal: Breakfast>, <Meal: Brunch>]
```

--

```
{% for i in chef.meal%} {{i}} {% endfor %}
```

Renders

```
[ < M e a l : B r e a k f a s t > , < M e a l : B r u n c h > ]
```

Here is the way I have the ModelMultipleChoiceField set up:

```
  meal = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        label=_("What is your best meal?"),
        queryset=Meal.objects.all(),
                                        required=True)
```

And the Meal model:

```
class Meal(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return "%s" % self.name
```

HttpResponse:

```
  data = {"profile":profile,
          "chef":chef}
  return render_to_response(template_name,
                            data,
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am passing 'chef' through to the template, and then pulled the meals from the Chef object.

Comment: How are you sending your meal objects to your template? Post the HttpResponse line or render_to_response lin from your code.

Comment: Added that above. I am pulling meals from the Chef model

Comment: How are you generating the Chef form, using modelform or forms.Form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use form fields inside a model. Instead make a foreign key from meal to Chef.

```
class Meal(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    chef = models.ForeignKey(Chef)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s" % self.name
```

Now inside the template use

```
{% for meal in chef.meal_set.all %}
     {{ meal }}
{% endfor %}
```

Ofcourse, instead of foreign field, there can be multiple-multiple relations between chef and meal models. Modify the code accordingly.

Comment: Ah Neo, I'm actually trying to display the data from the Chef object, not the form. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Comment: 'meal' is actually a form field and not an object. I'll repost the answer in that case.